# cannot perform edit operation in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to edit my User Class while passing the id and  while returning user object to controller it is getting error such as "There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500)".It is telling me to typecast to Optional.I don't know what to do.

UserService Class

```
public User editMyUser(int id) {
    return userRepository.findById(id);
}
```

Controller Class

```
@RequestMapping("/edit-user")
public String editUser(@RequestParam int id, HttpServletRequest request) {
    userService.deleteMyUser(id);

    request.setAttribute("user", userService.editMyUser(id));
    request.setAttribute("mode", "MODE_UPDATE");
    return "welcome";
}
```

Comment: what is the exact error stack trace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how `findById` looks like in the new version of Spring (according to docs):

```
public interface CrudRepository<T, ID extends Serializable>
      extends Repository<T, ID> {

    Optional<T> findById(ID primaryKey);

  // .... other methods ...
}
```

So, the first thing I would change in your code is :

```
public Optional<User> editMyUser(int id) {
    return userRepository.findById(id);
}
```

Make your method return `Optional<User>`, maybe this will help.

Also, be careful when using user returned by that new method, e.g. here

```
request.setAttribute("user", userService.editMyUser(id));
```

With `Optional` you need to use `get()` to obtain the actual user instance:

```
userService.editMyUser(id).get()
```

but first, you should check if that Optional actually contains the user:

```
Optional<User> optionalUser = userService.editMyUser(id);

if (optionalUser.isPresent()) {
    User user = optionalUser.get();
    // do whatever you need
} else {
   // means user is null - nothing found for ID
   // act accordingly
}
```

There is also a [good documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/) that Spring provides. Could be useful.

Happy Coding :)

Comment: i tried this fucntion and it shows such error "javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property [id] not found on type [java.util.Optional]"

Comment: I extended my answer, maybe it will help.

Comment: One more thing is that you call `userService.deleteMyUser(id);` first, so if it is done properly - the next line where you do `request.setAttribute("user", userService.editMyUser(id));` means that `userService.editMyUser` will return null all the time I guess. Because you delete first and then try to edit and this is kinda weird.

Comment: `"javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException` This means you are using user object on the page with EL expressions I guess, smth. like #{user.id} somewhere. Check my answer again with if/else for Optional - it should help.

Comment: thnk u john sryy i made silly mistake thnks alot it worked

Answer (score -1):

I let u here the cofiguration of the interface for a rest service that is working rihg now

```
@Api(value = "empleados", description = "the empleados API")
public interface EmpleadosApi {

    @ApiOperation(value = "Buscar empleados", notes = "", response = ResultadoBusquedaEmpleado.class, tags = {})
    @ApiResponses(value = {
        @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Búsqueda de empleados", response = ResultadoBusquedaEmpleado.class) })

    @RequestMapping(value = "/empleados", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    ResponseEntity<ResultadoBusquedaEmpleado> empleadosGet(
            @ApiParam(value = "Nombre de empleado") @RequestParam(value = "nombre", required = false) String nombre)
}
```